# Ajax not working in visual studio for windows(Blend)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, visual-studio-2013, blend

I am using ajax to login user but this script is not working. When i call login function to execute nothing happens..

```
function login() {
            var login = new XMLHttpRequest;
            var e = document.getElementById("email").value;
            var p = document.getElementById("password").value;                  
            var vars = "email=" + e + "&password=" + p;
            login.open("POST", "http://example.com/app/login.php", true);
            login.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            login.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (login.readyState == 4 && login.status == "200") {
                    var response = login.responseText;
                    //document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response;
                }
                document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Loggin in....";
                login.send(vars);
                if (response == "Sucess") {
                    window.location.replace("/logged.html");
                }
                else {
                    document.getElementById("status").innerHTML == "Login Failed";                    
                }
            }
        }
```

login.php contains following codes

```
require_once('../db_/connection.php');//Holds connection to database
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);//Sanitizing email
$pass = md5($_POST['password']);//Hashing password

$sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND password='$pass' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$check = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($check < 1){
    echo "fail";
    //mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
}
else{
    echo "Sucess";
    //mysqli_close($con);
    exit();
}
```

Calling login function does not execute the code.

Comment: have you tried to debug it? What where the results?

Comment: I debug php using get method instead of post method and the script is working fine.. The problem is with the ajax.. and i'm unable to find out.

Comment: i found that i wrote login.status = "200" instead of login.status = 200
i fixed that but still its not working

Comment: I debugged using firebug.. but the console is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Line 2: The parentheses are missing after `new XMLHttpRequest`
- Line 15: Your `if (response == "Sucess") { ... }` is misspelled and it gets executed **before** the ajax request is returned, because it's **asynchronous**

I made a working version at JSFiddle for you: http://jsfiddle.net/eRv83/

You might find the MDN referrence helpfull: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: What i did is after sending vars login.send(vars); i executed a function called execute() and put the condition in that function like this.
           login.send(vars);execute()                  
            }
        }
  function execute(){
     if (response == "Sucess") {
                        window.location.replace("about.php");
                    }
                    else {
                        document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = "Login Failed";
                    }
  }

But its still not working.

Comment: Adding your `execute` function is a good idea. By checking `login.status` you can now leave out the checking for `login.responseText`. Btw `if (response == "Sucess")` is **misspelled*.

Comment: I added the full solution for you

Comment: I debugged using firebug.. but the console is empty.

Comment: Thanx your script is working.. but don't know why mine not working even the console is empty ..

Comment: Check the JSFiddle ;-) It should clearify a bit better

Comment: I figured out...
i was sending the vars inside the onreadystatechange
i moved it out.. and it worked. 
by they way thanks for the help.